# Autodesk forge Create App not functioning

Tags: autodesk-forge

I filled out the entire form in all the required fields to create an application on the Autodesk site for their APIs. And the 'Create App' button endless loads with a few errors thrown in the browser console (errors tied to their 'create.js' script). Not sure if the feature for creating an app on the Autodesk site is my input error or my account/user type? I do have an active free trial which supposedly allows me to utilize the 'Create App' feature of the site for their APIs.

Any input on why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm also using 'https:/ /localhost:8080' as my callback for now since I do not have a need at the moment to set up an oAuth

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd.  It sounds like a glitch.

You should be seeing something like this: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/account/

However, if your browser has somehow a partial file set, then maybe it keeps loading the bad files.

One thing you can try is to clear your browser cache.

Again, sorry it's happening - it sounds very weird.

Let me know if clearing the cache fixes it.  (or try incognito mode in your browser, or try a different browser).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and I've tried both but netting the same result of a constant spinning/loading page. At this point I think it has to do with the type of account I have on forge's site. So I am hoping to hear back from their support team this week.

Comment: ok.  maybe try creating a new Forge trial account with a different email address, as a test.  If it proves to work, then let me know and we can try to fix the original forge account on our end.